# Some citations not working, but only on compilation of full document

Tags: citing

I am using overleaf.com for the following.

I have recently finished writing my thesis, the document is set up with a main.tex with \input{Chapter01.tex} for each chapter. Up until now I have been compiling only one chapter at a time for convenience, but now I need to compile the full document. Only when I compile the full document with every chapter included, about 30 of my citations fail with the error:

> You have cited something which is not included in your bibliography. Make sure that the citation (\cite{...}) has a corresponding key in your bibliography, and that both are spelled the same way.

Not only are these citations definitely included in my .bib file, but if I compile individual chapters, they work. I'll give an example of the first citation which fails below, which I include in the main text as `\cite{Broken}`

```
@Article{Broken,
    author = {{De Paolis}, F. and {Giordano}, M. and {Ingrosso}, G. and {Manni}, L. and {Nucita}, A. and {Strafella}, F.},
    title = "{The Scales of Gravitational Lensing}",
    journal = "{Universe}",
    year = 2016,
    month = 03,
    volume = 2, 
    number = 1,
}
```

This is the usepackage I'm using:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, maxnames=1, uniquelist=false, uniquename=false]{biblatex}
```

I tried following what was said in this question [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-or-bold-citation-key-instead-of-citation-number) , but It didn't help. My .blg file doesn't seem to have any issues:

> [0] Config.pm:354> INFO - This is Biber 2.7

> [0] Config.pm:357> INFO - Logfile is 'output.blg'

> [41] biber:303> INFO - === Tue Oct 20, 2020, 14:27:28

> [76] Biber.pm:359> INFO - Reading 'output.bcf'

> [265] Biber.pm:835> INFO - Found 258 citekeys in bib section 0

> [291] Biber.pm:3670> INFO - Processing section 0

> [308] Biber.pm:3840> INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'references.bib' for
> section 0

> [399] bibtex.pm:1435> INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8

> [505] bibtex.pm:1292> INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'references.bib'

> [2700] UCollate.pm:68> INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'

> [2701] UCollate.pm:68> INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'normalization = NFD' with 'normalization = prenormalized'

> [2701] Biber.pm:3499> INFO - Sorting list 'nyt/global/' of type 'entry' with scheme 'nyt' and locale 'en-US'

> [2701] Biber.pm:3505> INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'en-US'

> [3227] bbl.pm:608> INFO - Writing 'output.bbl' with encoding 'UTF-8'

> [3429] bbl.pm:712> INFO - Output to output.bbl

The issue is particularly difficult to troubleshoot as it only occurs when I compile the full document, and that takes several minutes.

Comment: Did you try to use `\nocite{*}` ?

Comment: I'm not sure what that is, what is it supposed to do? Adding it into my text didn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Well I never figured out the real issue, but I solved whatever it was by changing my biblatex backend to bibtex rather than biber.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else was also has this issue - in my case it turned out that a whitespace in a file name causes this. Everything else compiles just fine so I wasn't really focused on that, but if the citations are in a text file that has a whitespace in the title they won't show up!

Comment: I think you mean "a text file that has a whitespace in the file name".  In this context, "title" may be misinterpreted as the title of something in the text.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I think, your comment belongs to the answer of Víctor Souza Barboza below.